# web application architecture using nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

hi
I'm designing my first asp.net web app, using nHibernate as the data provider.

i've read a lot about nhibernate in web applications using session-per-request pattern.
my application will have a few pages which are 'monitors', meaning- they're updated automatically every few seconds to reflect recent changes to data.
in that case, my thought is that opening a session for every request would not make much sense, since I know that an identical request is sure to follow in a few seconds.

my thought is that session-per-conversation would make more sense for me, but I'm having trouble finding examples of implementations.
I'd appreciate any good resources for how to implement session-per-conversation, and any other ideas / suggestions you may have.

thanks

Jhonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session-per-request is still a good idea, as you don't know, in a web-scenerio, when a conversation ends. There's not much overhead to opening/closing a session, and the connection is only kept open whilst the session is in a transaction. <strike>, and, as a session wraps a database connection, you're simply using up connections from the connection pool by keeping your sessions open.</strike>

if you're stuck on a session-per-conversation stuff, look at [NHibernate.Burrow](http://nhforge.org/wikis/burrow/home.aspx) - this handles all the conversation/session management stuff for you.

Comment: The recommendation is good, but you have one point wrong: a session does **not** keep the connection open, except when inside a transaction.

Comment: I was also concerned, at first, about open db-connections, but as Diego pointed out- they're only open if a transaction is open.
Part of my motivation for having an open session is to utilize its caching mechanism, as some objects are not likely to change often (for example- if I monitor stock in my store, the store departments and sections aren't likely to change, while stock levels obviously are).
but then again, maybe I can utilize nhibernate's 2nd level cache.. any thoughts?

Comment: well, i've learned quite a bit about nHibernate and 2nd level cache since dec 11... :) indeed i'm using the session-per-request, as recommended, and 2nd level cache to hold the (relatively) static data (departments and sections). and it works very nicely. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use session-per-conversation, it seems to me that for the monitor pages the conversation would be ongoing during the entire user session. I would not recommend that approach because there are so many opportunities for problems in that scenario. I would recommend opening an IStatelessSession to update the monitor data display because that gives you the benefit of short-lived sessions without having the overhead of tracking object state.